# Get delivered time from Mailgun Delivered Webhook

Tags: webhooks, mailgun

Is there any way to get the delivery time from a Mailgun Delivery Webhook? By delivery time I mean the time the recipient's email provider received the email. I assume Mailgun has that information since they trigger a Delivery Event.

Analyzing the Delivered Event Webhook, I identified the following parameters that contain time information:

- timestamp - this parameter contains the datetime when Mailgun calls my API, so it can't be used.
- message-headers -> Date - This seems the time Mailgun sends the email to the recipient
- message-headers -> Received - This seems the time Mailgun receives the email from my email client

Thanks